# Possible to live-control an Arduino microcontroller from any Linux IoT board?

Tags: usb, arduino-micro

I'm working on a home project that centers around a non-Arduino Ubuntu IoT board but I'd like to add an ATmega32U4 chip for USB HID.

I'm thinking about using an Arduino Micro.

The signals to the Micro would have to come from my other board (maybe a Python script), but I haven't found instructions on how to send instructions **in real-time** from Other Board to Arduino Micro so they go straight through the Micro to the computer it's attached to.

How can one do this?

Comment: Am I right that your structure is Ubuntuboard --> Micro --> PC? Why do you need the Micro to communicate with the PC? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: @chrisl The Ubuntu board doesn't have a microcontroller and it doesn't work as a HID (mouse). That's what I need the Micro for.

Comment: @Juraj I don't understand what you mean by that comment.

Comment: can you just use a usb2serial adapter and the micros tx/rx?